# Why does ServiceLoader always re-instantiate a service?

Tags: java, serviceloader

Let's say I have a service interface `com.example.Service`.

For a test, I defined a

```
src/test/resources/META-INF/services/com.example.Service
```

file which contains

```
com.example.sometest.MockServiceImpl
```

the `MockServiceImpl` implements the interface.

Now, when doing a `ServiceLoader.load(Service.class)` and iterating over the result, my `MockServiceImpl` is always instantiated again. The javadoc for `ServiceLoader` states that it DOES maintain a cache, but my mock service does not seem to be cached.

Why is that so, and how do I get the `ServiceLoader` to cache it?

Answer (score 2):

I think API means that cache is per ServiceLoader instance: "Each invocation of the iterator method returns an iterator that first yields all of the elements of the cache...".

Comment: This might make sense. I am currently evaluating using injection instead.